# sqldeveloper on Host - VirtualBox (NAT network) - Virtual Machine Guest (ORA 12c DB)

Tags: oracle, virtualbox, nat

I have a problem with connection to ORA DB configured on Virtual Machine, where windows server 2016 is also installed.

1. In first configuration, I installed ORA DB 11G on Ubuntu, I opened port 1521 on Ubuntu. Virtualbox has NAT network setting and unfortunately it won't change because of administration restrictions (I won't get any new ip from bridged network,etc.). In virtual box NAT FORWARDING I set host port 2223 and guest port 1521.

Then I put a proper configuration in tnsnames in both machines (host and guest), next I connected to ORA DB on ubuntu via sql developer from the host machine using such a configuration:

```
UBUNTU_XE =
(DESCRIPTION =
(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 127.0.0.1)(PORT = 2223))
(CONNECT_DATA =
(SERVER = DEDICATED)
(SERVICE_NAME = XE)
)
)
```

It works perfectly

2. I configured ORA DB 12C on Windows Server 2016, in firewall inbound/outbound rule I opened port 1521 for Oracle. ORA Services is running on local user name: oracle which was created before ORA installation. I logged in as user name: oracle to conduct oracle installation. In virtual box NAT FORWARDING I set host port 2225 and guest port 1521.

Then I put a proper configuration in tnsnames in both machines (host and guest), next I connected to ORA DB on Windows server (guest) via sql developer from the host machine using such a configuration:

```
PDB_WIN_SERV16_FORWARD_127.0.0.1 =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 127.0.0.1)(PORT = 2225))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = pdb)
    )
 )
```

I tried also:

```
PDB_WIN_SERV16_FORWARD =
(DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 2225))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = pdb)
    )
  )
```

I want to confirm that above-mentioned connection works perfectly on Windows Server 2016 (of course with replacing port 2225 with 1521), on the other hand is not working on the host computer, the connection process in sql developer is still lasting. When I pick stop I get a communicate "Socket read interrupted, connect lapse 1857ms, authentication lapse 0 ms.

What is missing in configuration in windows server 2016 so as I could connect to ORA DB from the host?

Greetings

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the same as always. Listner.ora should have listened in a static registration on 10.0.2.15 (IP in NAT configuration). Then you have to restart listener via cmd line>lsnrctl restart. After you open listener port in inbound tcp rules and set proper nat forwarding in virtual box network configuration, e.g. PORT HOST 2223 GUEST PORT 1521, you will be able to connect to ORA DB on Virtual Machine using a connection from tnsnames on host computer:

WIN_SERV16_FORWARD =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 2223))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = pdb4)
    )
  )